# unix: get characters 10 to 80 in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, wc

I have a file containing line-separated text:

```
GCAACACGGTGGGAGCACGTCAACAAGGAGTAATTCTTCAAGACCGTTCCAAAAACAGCATGCAAGAGCG
GTCGAGCCTAGTCCATCAGCAAATGCCGTTTCCAGCAATGCAAAGAGAACGGGAAGGTATCAGTTCACCG
GTGACTGCCATTACTGTGGACAAAAAGGGCACATGAAGAGAGACTGTGACAAGCTAAAGGCAGATGTAGC
```

From this, I want to extract characters 10 to 80, so:

```
TGGGAGCACGTCAACAAGGAGTAATTCTTCAAGACCGTTCCAAAAACAGCATGCAAGAGCG
GTCGAGCCT
```

I have found how to count the characters in a file:

```
  wc -m file
```

and how to get a number of characters per line:

```
 awk '{print substr($0,2,6)}' file
```

but I cannot find a way to get the characters 10 to 80.

Newlines do not count as characters.

Any ideas?

Yes, this is DNA, from a full genome. I have extracted this bit of DNA from a fasta file containing different scaffolds (10 and 11 in this case) using

```
 awk '/scaffold_10\>/{p=1;next} /scaffold_11/{p=0;exit} p'
```

Ultimately, I would like to have a simple command to get characters 100 to 800 (or something like that) from that specified scaffold.

EDIT: Question continues here: [use gff2fasta instead of a bash script to get parts of DNA sequences out of a full genome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356527/bash-script-to-get-parts-of-dna-sequences-out-of-a-full-genome)

Comment: Is this, a file about DNA information?

Comment: `dd if=file bs=1 count=71 skip=9 status=none`

Comment: @Spandan yes, this is DNA (whole genome, need to extract certain bits of it...)

Comment: Sato's comment gives a neat solution if the file _only_ contains DNA. If it's a fasta-formatted file with one or several headers, his solution sadly won't work.

Comment: awk '{print substr($0,10,70)}' file

Comment: @Kamaraj: this does not work the way I need it. It will print the characters 10 to 70 for each line (if the linea do have that many characters, which they do not...)

Comment: what you exactly want ? say.. we have 100 lines in first line.. 150 lines in second line.. 30 lines in third line.. what is your usecase here ?

Comment: The amount of characters per line is always the same. I want to get the characters 10 to 80 from that file, not characters 10 to 80 on each line

Comment: from man command...  substr(s, i [, n])      Returns the at most n-character substring of s starting at i.  If n is omitted, the rest of s is used.

Comment: check my answer.. hope it answers for you

Comment: @gugy, just to clarify, your count only includes the characters GCAT, but the source file still has newlines which should not be counted on output? Also, what size can the source file be?

Comment: @ikkachu: file contains only GATC and newlines, newlines should not be counted. Sourcefile is usually around 20MB (ca 276185 lines) for a full genome and less for only a scaffold

Comment: @gugy Newlines should not be counted but do they need to be present for formatting as your sample o/p shows?

Comment: The `dd` solution works in a pinch but you need to realise that there are *proper parsers* for Fasta files. **Do not hack your own parser** using command line tools, use the proper tools. There are already enough crappy bioinformatics tools that randomly break because people hacked together a bad solution instead of using proper tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder how the line feed in the file should be handled. Does that count as a character or not?

If we just should take from byte 10 and print 71 bytes (A,C,T,G and linefeed) then Sato Katsura solution is the fastest (here assuming GNU `dd` or compatible for `status=none`, replace with `2> /dev/null` (though that would also hide error messages if any) with other implementations):

```
 dd if=file bs=1 count=71 skip=9 status=none
```

If the line feed should be skipped then filter them out with `tr -d '\n'`:

```
 tr -d '\n' < file | dd bs=1 count=70 skip=9 status=none
```

If the Fasta-header should be skipped it is:

```
 grep -v '^[;>]' file | tr -d '\n' | dd bs=1 count=70 skip=9 status=none
```

`grep -v '^[;>]' file` means skip all lines that start with `;` or `>`.

Comment: I like this solution! can it be modified to only start counting after the occurence of >scaffold_2 ? the current answer ignores the lines starting with >, but counts from the beginning of the file, if I understand correctly?

Comment: It is best if you change the original question. Show exactly what the input and the output is and then someone would come with a solution. I'm not a `sed` expert but this one should do it: `cat file | sed -n -e '/>scaffold_2/,$p' | grep -v '^>' | cut -zc 10-80` but I think grep could be avoided with the right `sed ` option. (this `cut`-thing is good).

Answer (score 7):

```
$ cat file1
GCAACACGGTGGGAGCACGTCAACAAGGAGTAATTCTTCAAGACCGTTCCAAAAACAGCATGCAAGAGCG
GTCGAGCCTAGTCCATCAGCAAATGCCGTTTCCAGCAATGCAAAGAGAACGGGAAGGTATCAGTTCACCG
GTGACTGCCATTACTGTGGACAAAAAGGGCACATGAAGAGAGACTGTGACAAGCTAAAGGCAGATGTAGC
```

check the length of each line

```
$ awk '{print length,$0}' file1
70 GCAACACGGTGGGAGCACGTCAACAAGGAGTAATTCTTCAAGACCGTTCCAAAAACAGCATGCAAGAGCG
70 GTCGAGCCTAGTCCATCAGCAAATGCCGTTTCCAGCAATGCAAAGAGAACGGGAAGGTATCAGTTCACCG
70 GTGACTGCCATTACTGTGGACAAAAAGGGCACATGAAGAGAGACTGTGACAAGCTAAAGGCAGATGTAGC
```

print the characters of 10-80

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,10,70)}' RS= file1
TGGGAGCACGTCAACAAGGAGTAATTCTTCAAGACCGTTCCAAAAACAGCATGCAAGAGCG
GTCGAGCC
```

That assumes the input contains no empty line (`RS=` enables the *paragraph mode* where every record is a paragraph (paragraphs being delimited by sequences of empty lines)) and it implies loading the whole file in memory.

Comment: alright, that works. thx!

Comment: I wonder... Does `awk` read the whole file into memory when doing it that way?

Comment: yes.. that's correct. if the file size is very big.. then we encounter with slowness.

Comment: Also, I think you need to count one character for the newline in the middle. (Now you're missing the final `T` from the example.) That gets more annoying if the part to be picked is longer, and especially if the lines are of different lengths for some reason.

Comment: Since you need to print only the first 80 chars, adding `;exit` after `print substr(..)` might help to improve performance forcing awk to exit and not read the rest file.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I think that because `RS` is empty, the whole file is read before it gets to the `substr()` call.

Comment: @Kusalananda Probably you are right....

Comment: Remove the new-lines before doing `substr`, e.g. `gsub("\n", "")`

Comment: @Kusalananda, no, `RS=` is the _paragraph mode_. For slurp mode, see [Slurp-mode in awk?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/304457)

Answer (score 5):

For bytes (so would also work for single-byte characters like in your sample):

```
dd bs=1 skip=9 count=71 < file 2> /dev/null
```

Or more efficiently with GNU `dd`:

```
dd iflag=fullblock,skip_bytes,count_bytes skip=9 count=71 status=none < file
```

For characters, with `zsh`:

```
{
  IFS= read -ru0 -k9 discard &&
    IFS= read -ru0 -k71 text &&
    printf %s $text
} < file
```

(won't print anything if there are fewer than 80 characters in the file).

`ksh93` and `bash` have a `-N` option similar to `zsh`'s `-k`, but they don't support the NUL characters and [the `bash` one is buggy](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg19559.html).

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='.{1}' -v ORS= 'NR>=10 {print RT}; NR == 80 {exit}'
```

We use `.{1}` as `.` being a single character would not be treated as a regexp.

Another option is to convert to a character encoding that has a fixed number of bytes per character (and has all possible characters) like UTF-32LE that has 4 bytes per character:

```
< file iconv -t UTF-32LE |
   dd bs=4 skip=9 count=71 2> /dev/null |
   iconv -f UTF-32LE
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind bringing the entire contents into memory, and having the line *unwrapped*, you can use command substitution to read it in (thanks to [George Vasiliou](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/188385/george-vasiliou) for the `tr` improvement!)

```
data=$( tr -d '\n' < inputfile )
```

then print from (zero-based) 10, for a length of 70 bytes:

```
printf "%s\n" "${data:9:70}"
```

Comment: Why not `data=$( tr -d '\n' < inputfile )`  to avoid mem double loading?

Comment: Only because I didn't think of it, @GeorgeVasiliou!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the newline characters are not significant to the data, but just formatting in the file (code not tested):

```
BEGIN {
  linesize=70;
  start=10;
  end=80;
}
// {
  if ((NR>=int(start/linesize) && (NR<=int(end/linesize)) {
     from = NR==int(start/linesize) ? start % linesize : 0;
     to   = NR==int(end/linesize) ? (end % linesize)-from : linesize+1;
     print substr($0, from, to);
  }
  if (NR==int(end/linesize)) exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -l -0777pe '
   my($start, $stop) = qw/10 80/; $delta = $stop - $start--;
   (undef, $_, $a) = unpack "A${start}A${delta}A*";
   $_ .= $1 while length() - y/\n/\n/ < $delta and $a =~ /(.)/g;
'  scaffolded_file_10
```