# use gff2fasta instead of a bash script to get parts of DNA sequences out of a full genome

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut, bioinformatics

**EDIT and a solution**

Because my original question was badly phrased and I was trying to re-invent the wheel I am answering my own question now (maybe it helps someone else):

gff2fasta is a tool which does exactly what I need, which is to extract a given piece of DNA from a full genome (A huge file in fasta format called FULLGENOME.fasta).

If I know where the piece I want is, I can make a file called TEST.gff where I specify the scaffold (here: sca_5_chr5_3_0) and the beginning (here: 2390621) and end (here: 2391041) of my piece for gff2fasta, for example:

```
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI CDS 2390621 2391041 .   +   0   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; proteinId 40463;
```

Then I only need to run

```
 gff2fasta.pl -gff TEST.gff -fasta FULLGENOME.fasta -out test
```

gff2fasta will then get the info from TEST.gff and output the bit I want in the file called test, which will look like this:

```
 >sca_5_chr5_3_0_2390621_2391041_F
 ATGACGACCCGCGCACCCAAAGACACATACGCTCAGCCCGACTATGAGGAGGCTCACCTAGCGACGTTTGCAGCCCCAAA
 AGGCTACCCTATCGAGTCTATGCTACCCCCTAGCGTGAAGAGGGAGACCTTTGAACAGGCCCTAGCCGAGTTTACCGACG
 CTATCGGCAAAGATTATGTCTTTATCGGCGATGCTCTCTCTCACTACATCGATCCCTACGACATCTATATCGATGATAGT
 GAGAGAAGGAGGATGCCGAGCGCGGCTGTTTGGTACGTAACGCGGCACCCATCGAAACCTAGCAGCACTGACAAGTTTCC
 GCGTCTAGTCCCTCTTCGCTCGAGGAAGCTAAGCAGGCTCTCAAGGTTGCGAACAAATACGGCATTCCGATCTGGGCATT
 TTCCAGAGGCAAGAACCTGGG
```

Thanks to terdon and everyone else for the help!

### -------------

This is the continuation of this question, with more info and details [unix: get characters 10 to 80 in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356297/unix-get-characters-10-to-80-in-a-file#356352)

I think I am almost there, but still need some help.

I have tried to explain it as clearly as possible, but I am aware that it is a very specialized question, so please let me know if I can clarify something further!

What I have are three files:

*note to admin: is it possible to upload files? I have no clue how to...*

One **file** (N_haematococca_1.fasta) from which I need to extract a name:

```
 head -1 N_haematococca_1.fasta | cut -f4 -d'|'
```

this name in this case is:

```
 e_gw1.5.88.1
```

*Problem 1: The code above works fine but I have troubles getting the name (e_gw1.5.88.1) saved in a variable that I can use for later...*

I want to save that name in a variable, let's call it:

```
 firstline
```

A **second** file (Necha2_best_models.gff) where I want all the lines where this name occurs:

```
 grep -ir "e_gw1.5.88.1" --include="Necha2*.gff" > Necha2_in_genome.list
```

but with the named variable:

```
 grep -ir $firstline --include="Necha2*.gff" > Necha2_in_genome.list
```

*This works for the use of "e_gw1.5.88.1"...*

The file I am creating here tells me the name of the DNA-fragment I want to cut (sca_5_chr5_3_0) and which bit of it I need (from character number 2390621 to character number 2392655).
I need that info to get the right bits out of the third file

```
 a=(`awk -F '\t' '{print $4}' Necha2_in_genome.list`)

 startDNA=${a[1]}
 endDNA=${a[${#a[@]}-1]}

 #add 1000 or other number, depending on the problems with the gene
 correctedstartDNA=$(($startDNA-1000))
 correctedendDNA=$(($endDNA-1000))
```

In a **third** file from which I want to cut certain parts after a keyword (sca_5_chr5_3_0) in this case:

Thanks to Kamaraj and hschou I have a partial solution to this now:

```
 cat Necha2_scaffolds.fasta | sed -n -e '/sca_5_chr5_3_0/,$p' | grep -v '^>' | tr -d '\n'|awk -v start="${correctedstartDNA}" -v end="${correctedendDNA}" '{print substr($0,start,end)}' RS= Necha2_scaffolds.fasta
```

However if I debug this with small numbers:

```
 cat Necha2_scaffolds.fasta | sed -n -e '/sca_5_chr5_3_0/,$p' | grep -v '^>' |  tr -d '\n'|awk -v start=10 -v end=20 '{print substr($0,start,end)}' RS= Necha2_scaffolds.fasta
```

I get this output:

```
 r1_1_0
 CCTTATCCTAGCG
 nmapped
 CTTATATATTAT
 nmapped
 TAAAAGGAGTTA
 unmapped
 TCTTATATAAA
 unmapped
 AATCTTAAGAA
```

It seem the RS option is ignored and it only prints the characters 10 to 20 for certain lines. I have no clue why these lines are selected.

```
 sca_5_chr5_3_0
```

only occurs once in the file.

other names that are there are

```
 >sca_66_unmapped 
 >sca_67_unmapped
```

etc

I have to get this info from 178 genomes, they are all huge files and searching manually is just not an option.

HOW the files look:

N_haematococca_1.fasta (file 1) is a normal fasta file:

```
 >jgi|Necha2|40463|e_gw1.5.88.1
 MTTRAPKDTYAQPDYEEAHLATFAAPKGYPIESMLPPSVKRETFEQALAEFTDAIGKDYVFIGDALSHYI
 DPYDIYIDDSERRRMPSAAVCPSSLEEAKQALKVANKYGIPIWAFSRGKNLGYGGPSARVNGSVAFDLHR
```

Necha2_best_models.gff (file 2) looks like this (just longer):

```
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI exon    2390621 2390892 .   +   .   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; transcriptId 40463
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI CDS 2390621 2390892 .   +   0   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; proteinId 40463; exonNumber 1
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI start_codon 2390621 2390623 .   +   0   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI exon    2390949 2391041 .   +   .   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; transcriptId 40463
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI CDS 2390949 2391041 .   +   2   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; proteinId 40463; exonNumber 2
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI exon    2391104 2391311 .   +   .   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; transcriptId 40463
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI CDS 2391104 2391311 .   +   2   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; proteinId 40463; exonNumber 3
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI exon    2391380 2392367 .   +   .   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; transcriptId 40463
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI CDS 2391380 2392367 .   +   0   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; proteinId 40463; exonNumber 4
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI exon    2392421 2392485 .   +   .   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; transcriptId 40463
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI CDS 2392421 2392485 .   +   1   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; proteinId 40463; exonNumber 5
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI exon    2392541 2392657 .   +   .   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; transcriptId 40463
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI CDS 2392541 2392657 .   +   0   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"; proteinId 40463; exonNumber 6
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI stop_codon  2392655 2392657 .   +   0   name "e_gw1.5.88.1"
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI exon    2396205 2396730 .   +   .   name "e_gw1.5.227.1"; transcriptId 41333
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI CDS 2396205 2396730 .   +   0   name "e_gw1.5.227.1"; proteinId 41333; exonNumber 1
 sca_5_chr5_3_0 JGI start_codon 2396205 2396207 .   +   0   name "e_gw1.5.227.1"
```

Necha2_scaffolds.fasta (file 3) looks a bit like this (much longer GATC bits...):

```
 >sca_8_chr1_1_0
 CCTTATCCTAGCGAGGATTAAGGTCCTCGAAAAGAAAGGCAAAGATATAAAGGTAATATAATAGAAGATT
 AAGGTATTCTAAGTAAAGGTTATAAAGAAATAAAATAAGAAGAATATTTATAGGCTAAGAAAGACCCCCC
 TAAAGGTTAAGGACTTAATATTAAGATTTAATATTCCCTAATTAATTAATATATTAATAAAAATAAAGAT
 >sca_5_chr5_3_0
 ATGACCACTATATCCATCGGCACAACGGCGTTAATCACATTTGGGTCTGCAATTTTCTGTTTTTGCGGTT
 TTCATGTCGGTTCCAACGGGCGGAGCTCGACCAAGAATTACATACATTACGTGGCGCGAGCGCTCTACCC
 TCTGGGACATGAAGGGGACGAGGAGTCTGGAGAGGTTCATGTTTGGAATCACAGCATGGTACTGCGGCAC
 CCTACCTTGGTCATTCGTTGGTCTCTTTTTTTCAGGGTATGGACGCAGACTCTCAGACTCGCTCTGCTTT
 >sca_67_unmapped
 CTACAGGAAGCCCTAGAGGCCCTGCAAGACCTTCCAAAGCAGCACTCTTTGCTTCTTCTTAGAGGCAGTA
 TCCAGCTTCTTCTAAGGCACCTCCAGAGGCAGCTAGACCCAACCGGGCTAAAAGACCTTTGGGAAGAGGC
 TAATACCCTTATAAGAGAGGCTATTATAGCCCTAGTGGCTAGAAGCCCTAGTGAGAGCCCTAAAGAGCCT
 AATTCAAGCCTTATAGCCCTTCCAGTCAGAGAGGGAGGCCTAGGAATACCCTTACACAAGGACCTAGCCC
```

**Expected final output**: Is a single bit of text after the >sca_5_chr5_3_0 keyword

```
 TTCATGTCGGTTCCAACGGGCGGAGCTCGACCAAGAATTACATACATTACGTGGCGCGAGCGCTCTACCC
 TCTGGGACATGAAGGGGACGAGGAGTCTGGAGAGGTTCATGTTTGGAATCACAGCATGGTACTGCGGCAC
 CCTACCTTGGTCATTCGTTGGTCTCTTTTTTTCAGGGTATGGACGCAGACTCTCAG
```

Comment: [You got bad advice/aren't using a version of `cut` with a `-z` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356297/unix-get-characters-10-to-80-in-a-file?rq=1#comment631544_356369).

Comment: what is the contents of Necha2_scaffolds.fasta and what is expected output ?

Comment: (It's a bit odd to accept an answer that *doesn't* work for you)

Comment: @Michael: apparently cut from the GNU coreutils from 2016 has a -z option... see in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356297/unix-get-characters-10-to-80-in-a-file DarkHeart's answer and Jeffs comment. SO the only thing I need to do is figure out how to get that option on my ubuntu running... ;P

Comment: Demonstrably you're not using that.

Comment: @Kamaraji: see edit

Comment: is the awk command not working to extract the characters ?

Comment: @Kamaraj If I use awk '{print substr($0,$correctedstartDNA,$correctedendDNA)}' RS= Necha2_scaffolds.fasta I get "no output" (empty lines). Am I doing sth wrong?

Comment: @Michael: yes you are very right... took me some time to figure out...

Comment: awk -v start="${correctedstartDNA}" -v end="${correctedendDNA}" '{print substr($0,start,end)}' RS= Necha2_scaffolds.fasta

Comment: @Kamaraj: Alrigth, cool that works. Now I need to have a way to only count after the occurence of "sca_5_chr5_3_0". Let's see if I can figure this out ;)

Comment: check for index function of awk

Comment: Are you just trying to extract the regions defined in a gff file from a multifasta file? Your question is kind of confusing. You seem to be completely ignoring the strand for example. How are you dealing with gff regions defined on the negative strand? And your partial solution won't work. You can have a region that spans multiple lines of your fasta file.

Comment: @terdon: I want only parts of the regions defined in the gff file.  I do not want the entire scaffold but only the region of the scaffold I know my gene of interest is in. I need to do manual gene model editing for that gene of interest... I am not interested in the negative strand.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us a minimal example of all files. Most people will have no idea what a gff file looks like. Show us a small gff and a small fasta file and the output you would expect from them. Also explain whether you can have sequences in the - strand so we know whether our answers will need to deal with that as well. Oh and also explain that a fasta sequence is split into multiple lines, this is essential for your answer since when looking for a character range, we will need to concatenate the sequence lines.

Comment: Feel free to come to [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) and ping me if you need help formulating this.

Comment: *> note to admin: is it possible to upload files? I have no clue how to...* Please don't do that -- post a short, self-contained, working example instead.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but what we need is i) short example input files and ii) **the output you would want from those input files**.

Comment: As a general rule, it is almost never a good idea to use `grep`, `sed` and `awk` in a single pipeline, since `sed` can do everything `grep` can, and `awk` can do everything `sed` can.